# Zoom in animation between activities

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I am creating an Android application. I want to open the new activity with zoom in transition. I have some buttons in my current activity. When I click one button new activity will open from the button's position. I try to use the following code. But no transition will appear. I am using the following xml and java codes.

**zoom_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="70%"
        android:pivotY="70%"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

and **zoom_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="70%"
        android:pivotY="70%"
        android:toXScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="0.5" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

And in my java code I call it like

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_in,R.anim.zoom_out);
```

With these code no effect will appear. Could someone please help me to finds out what is the issue?

Comment: where are you calling this?

Comment: You mean this (overridePendingTransition(zoom_in, zoom_out);)?  After intent . StartActivity(intent)..

Comment: Try to call it onResume or onStart and onFinish of the other activity.

Comment: have you tired increasing duration?

Comment: Yes I tried but no transition will happening I am not able to find the issue.

Comment: post some more of java code.

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/28/zoom-in-animation-between-two-activities/ check this

Comment: @KaranMer I tried with exact code no use it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the attribute: `android:fillAfter="true"` 
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

Comment: Where you declare overridePendingTransition method?
Try to put this method after setContentView (in onCreate method) in the second activity :)

Comment: OMG i use the method overridePendingTransition after startActivity and it work properly.! I think the isses is you set duration 800 is too fast.

Answer (score 0):

place both animation xml files `zoom_in.xml` and `zoom_out.xml` in `res/anim`
directory and start animation like this :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_in,R.anim.zoom_out);
```

Comment: Sorry I am doing the exact same thing. Please check my updated question.